# Vertical-Align Divs in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a `header` consisting of an `h1` and a `nav` element. I want the bottom of the `nav` to be aligned with the bottom of the `h1`.

Here's what I've tried:

#### HTML

```
<header>
    <h1>Web site Header</h1>
      <nav>
         <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
 </header>
```

#### CSS

```
header {vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%; height: 300px;}
h1 {vertical-align: bottom; float: left;}
nav {vertical-align: bottom; float: right;}
nav ul li {display: inline;}
```

I could do this by setting exact margins for my elements, but I thought this would be cleaner (if it's possible). Any advice on how to fix it/if it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: typo: closing `</nav>` missing the `/` and nav rule missing last `;`.

Answer (score 1):

As clean as it can get:

```
<style>
    header > * { display: inline-block; }
    nav li { display: inline; }
</style>
```

Direct `header` descendants are now inline blocks, i.e. they don't push surrounding content to flow beneath them, yet they can still utilize the `margin` and `padding` property as blocks.

Comment: Thanks kRON but no luck :( . I'd still need to use margin and padding to position it correctly. That said, I'm pretty sure there's no way not to.

Comment: Well, if you provide more context I'd be happy to help. In any case, I wouldn't fret over it too much. Every single header feature that has presentation that you incorporate should be approached with trepidation; styles for page headers are complete voodoo on any Web site--you'll never find a structure with fewer elements (types and count both), but with so many nested and overlapping style rules anywhere!!! I just landed on Yahoo! to reassure myself after the neat SO header and almost puked when I traversed through their header, which accounts for the Web majority as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do in many different ways. Margins are designed for positioning, but if you'd rather not use margins or padding, you can use absolute positioning:

CSS:

```
header
{
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
h1
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: 32px;
}
nav
{
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul
{
  bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
nav ul li
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>Web site Header</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This relies on knowing the height of the header, and setting both the header and the nav to the same heights/margins.